# How can I get the last message in the thread?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, spreadsheet

i use the following code in Google Apps Script and i wanna get last reply every mail list. This code gets every threads first mail instead of last mail.

````
 var myspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var mysheet = myspreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
 var start = 0;
 var max = 399;
 var count =0;
 var row = mysheet.getLastRow()+1
 while(count < 7) 
 {

   var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start , max);
   var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads); 
   var froms = [];
    messages.get
      for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
    {
       froms.push([messages[i][0].getId(),messages[i][0].getSubject(),messages[i][0].getTo(),messages[i][0].getFrom(),messages[i][0].getCc(),messages[i][0].getDate(),messages[i][0].getReplyTo()]);
    }

    mysheet.getRange(mysheet.getLastRow()+1,1,threads.length,7).setValues(froms);

    start =  start + 100;
    count++;
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot going on in this script that may need to be changed.

So the following lines are limited to getting the last message of each thread. And then pushing the details of that last message into the array `from[]`.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) { // Loop through the threads

    var thisThread = threads[i]; // Get a speific thread

    var messages = thisThread.getMessages(); // Get the messages in that thread

    var messageCount = thisThread.getMessageCount(); // Count the number of messages in that thread

    var lastMessage = messages[messageCount - 1]; // Get the last message in that thread. The first message is numbered 0.

    froms.push([lastMessage.getId(), lastMessage.getSubject(), lastMessage.getTo(), lastMessage.getFrom()...]);

  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ADW. i tried your way but Apps Script gives this error:
TypeError: Cannot call method "getId" of undefined. (line 19, file "Code")

Comment: I'm sorry. `lastMessage` was wrong. Have edited it in my post.