# Google Script to save attachment to GDrive, without duplicating

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

Using Google Workspaces, I need a script to move an attachment from a daily email - with always the same sender, subject and attachment name - to a folder in Google Drive.

I've tried several of the scripts found on here, which all move the attachment to drive - but when I set the periodic triggers for execution, all prior and already moved attachments are moved again and duplicates are created.
How can i do this without having to delete either the email or the previous file?

Below seems to half work - but I need this to only apply to NEW emails that haven't already had the attachments moved. Would also be great if there was a way to specify only the xls attachment but I don't know where to insert that bit

```js
function myFunction() {
var emailSubject = ""; // YOUR EMAIL SUBJECT
var folderId = ""; //YOUR FOLDER ID (FOUND IN URL)

var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

var thread = GmailApp.search(emailSubject)[0];
var message = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(thread)[0];
var attachments = message.getAttachments();

for (var i = 0; i<attachments.length; i++){
folder.createFile(attachments[i].copyBlob());
}
}
```

Comment: `thread.addLabel(label);` add a label to the mail after storing the attachment, next time onwards while doing search using `GmailApp.search(subject  -label:labelname)`. This means search all mails except this label

Comment: have you tried to check if the email is unread with the method [isUnread()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#isunread)

Answer (score 0):

Lauren, here are two ways depending on how your mailbox is used:

1. The script could look for unread emails with that subject and attachment. Save the attachment and then mark the email as read. That way you won't get duplicates.
2. If the email box is used "manually" as well, i.e. the email might get marked "read" by folks using the mailbox, here is the 2nd way.
   a. create a label in the mailbox
   b. create a filter that attaches this label to new emails with that subject and attachment.
   c. change the script to look for emails with that label. And once the attachment is saved, remove the label from the email.

Comment: Thanks! I have gone with your 1st suggestion. Seems to be working, but sometimes a random old attachment is being saved as well as a new one. Does the script look correct to you?
function saveAttachmentsTest() {
  const destinationFolderId = '';
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('');
  const emails = GmailApp.search('label:' AND label:unread');
  for (const email of emails) {
    for (const message of email.getMessages()) {
      for (const attachment of message.getAttachments()) {
        folder.createFile(attachment);
      }
message.markRead(); // Mark as read
    }
  }
}

Comment: Apologies I don't know how to do this without losing formatting

Comment: function saveAttachmentsTest() {
  const destinationFolderId = '';
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('');
  const emails = GmailApp.search('label: AND label:unread');
  for (const email of emails) {
    for (const message of email.getMessages()) {
      for (const attachment of message.getAttachments()) {
        folder.createFile(attachment);
      }
message.markRead(); // Mark as read
    }
  }
}

Comment: The issue might be that if the new email is part of an old thread, the attachments to the older messages in the thread might also be saved. You can avoid that by picking the last message in the thread. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57594055/how-can-i-get-the-last-message-in-the-thread)